# What was the significance of overemphasis of conservation of resources posters?

Tags: props, blackmail

In the start of the Bollywood film *Blackmail*, we see a lot of resource conservation posters, like "Save water", "Use the hand dryer for 10 seconds only" etc etc. And those posters were shown in focus.

What was the significance of so much emphasis on those posters?